# Items with in a div move after JS event

Tags: html, css

I'm having some CSS styling issues.

*Firstly, excuse the poor styling - I've just sorted out the logic of the game and am now working on the styling*

The game is a simple game of rock paper scissors. And everytime I click on a square (which represents either rock paper scissors), the game logic is run and either you or the computer player get a point. Once both players get their score updated, the items with the div `stripe` get pushed up in the div.

I'm not sure if this a html/css issue, or an issue with JS - but what I'd like is the items with the `stripe` div to remain center at all times.

I've included images to show you what I mean - As I'm sure what I said is confusing you all.

Cheers

[image: Image One]

[image: Image Two]

Code:

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "Montserrat", "Avenir";
}

#header {
  line-height: 1.1;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  font-weight: normal;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

#stripe {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 auto;
  height: 50px;
}

#reset {
  width: 5%;
}

#message {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 10%;
}

#yourScore {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2%;
}

#compScore {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 2%;
}

.option {
  width: 30%;
  background: steelblue;
  padding-bottom: 30%;
  float: left;
  margin: 1.66%;
  border-radius: 25px;
  transition: background .5s;
  -webkit-transition: .5s;
  -moz-transition: .5s;
}

#buttons {
  margin: 20px auto;
  max-width: 600px;
}
```

```html
<div id="header">
  <h1>Rock Paper Scissors</h1>
</div>

<div id="stripe">
  <button id="reset">Reset</button>
  <span id="message"><p></p></span>
  <span id="yourScore" data-value="0"><p>0</p></span>
  <span id="compScore" data-value="0"><p>0</p></span>
</div>

<div id="buttons">
  <div id="rock" class="option">rock</div>
  <div id="paper" class="option">paper</div>
  <div id="scissors" class="option">scissors</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your JavaScript? From what I can mess with it does the thing where it aligns everything on top if  #message, #yourScore, and #compScore all have the `p` element removed. Possibly like you are setting innerHTML on the `p`'s parent.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned in the comments, you are probably loosing the `p`s when updating the inner html of `#message` `#yourScore` and `#compScore`.

I would suggest you remove all the `p`s from within the stripe and change the stying to add some top/bottom paddings:

```
#stripe {
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 15px 0;
}
```

Comment: Yes, you guys are correct. But why am I losing the ps when updating the inner html? Can you please explain that for me?

Comment: Because you are targeting the element by id, in your case the `span`. Then you replace the html of the span from being `<p></p>` with `text`. If you want to keep the `p` you can set the innerHTML to `<p>text</p>`. By the way, a `p` inside `span` is invalid html - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Inline_elements